# PHP Send Script -- Checkbox verify

Tags: php, html

URL: http://medtransportcenter.com/medical-transportation/los-altos/
I have just recently updated my form to now include a checkbox. I'm trying to get the send-form.php script to recognize whether or not the checkbox was checked or not when it sends the confirmation email. I did some research and found that the following code will do the trick for checking whether it was checked. But, I inserted it and kept giving me syntax error when testing the form. I included the additional code I have for the php script and checkbox field below. Please help with this.

My whole form HTML:

```
<div class="form-box">
<!-- Form -->

<form id="proForm" action="send-form.php" method="post" >

<h2 style="text-align:center;">REQUEST INFO</h2>
        <h3 style="text-align:center;">FREE EXPERT ADVICE</h3>
<div class="form-content">
<!-- Form -->

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">

<!--tr>
<td class="field-full" colspan="2">
    <div class="label"><label for="www"><b>Your website URL</b></label></div>
    <input id="www" class="required defaultInvalidUrl url" maxlength="40" name="www" type="text" tabindex="2" value="http://" />
</td>
</tr-->
<tr>
<th class="label" align="right"><label for="nameis">Your name</label></td>:<td class="field">
  <input id="nameis" class="required defaultInvalidEmail nameis" maxlength="40" name="nameis" type="text" tabindex="2" value="Required" 
        onfocus="if (this.value == 'Required') {this.value = '';}"
        onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Required';}" size="40" />
</td>
</tr>                                   
<tr>
<th class="label" align="right"><label for="email">E-mail</label></td>:<td class="field">
  <input id="email" class="required defaultInvalidEmail email" maxlength="40" name="email" type="text" tabindex="3" value="Required" 
        onfocus="if (this.value == 'Required') {this.value = '';}"
        onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Required';}" size="40" />
</td>
</tr>   

<tr>
<th class="label" align="right"><label for="phone">Best Phone:</label></td>
<td class="field">
  <input id="phone" class="required defaultInvalidEmail phone" maxlength="40" name="phone" type="text" tabindex="4" value="Required" size="30" 
        onfocus="if (this.value == 'Required') {this.value = '';}"
        onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Required';}" size="40" />
</td>
</tr>   

<tr>
<th class="label" align="right"><label for="bestime">
Best time to reach you:</label></td>
<td class="field">
  <input maxlength="40" size="30" name="bestime" type="text" tabindex="5" value="" />
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th class="label" align="right"><label for="phone">
Origin:</label></td>
<td class="field">
  <input maxlength="40" size="30" name="origin" type="text" tabindex="5" value="" />
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th class="label" align="right"><label for="phone">
Destination:</label></td>
<td class="field">
  <input maxlength="40" size="30" name="destination" type="text" tabindex="5" value="" />
</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<th class="label" align="right"><label for="msg">
Message:</label></td>
<td class="field">
  <textarea rows="3" cols="31" name="msg" tabindex="6"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th class="label"><label for="brochure">Request Brochures</label></td>
<td class="field">
  <input type="checkbox" name="brochure[]" value="Yes" />
</td>
</tr>       

<!--tr>
<td class="field-full" colspan="2">
    <div class="label"><label for="msg"><b>Other</b></label></div>
  <textarea rows="3" cols="30" name="msg" tabindex="9"></textarea>
</td>
</tr-->

</table>

<div class="terms">By clicking 'Send',<br/> you accept our <a onclick="showTerms()">Privacy Policy</a>. <br /><span style="font-size:14px;">Phone: 800-282-6878.</span></div>

<div class="btn-box"><input class="button1" type="submit" value="Send" tabindex="10" /></div>


<!-- END Form -->
</form> 
</div>
```

My PHP Script

```
<?php

//$www = '';    
$email = '';
$nameis = '';
$phone = '';
$bestime = '';
//$address = '';
$origin = '';
$destination = '';
$msg = '';
$brochure = '';

function getIp()
{if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){
    $ip_address=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
}

if (!isset($ip_address)){
        if (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) 
        $ip_address=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
return $ip_address;
}

if(isset($_POST['brochure'])){
$brochure_checked = $_POST['brochure'];} 
else {
$brochure_not_checked = $_POST['brochure'];
}


//taking info about date, IP and user agent

$timestamp = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$ip   = getIp();
$host = gethostbyaddr($ip); 
$user_agent = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];


//taking the data from form 

//$www = addslashes(trim($_POST['www']));   
$email = addslashes(trim($_POST['email']));
$nameis = addslashes(trim($_POST['nameis']));
$phone = addslashes(trim($_POST['phone']));
$bestime = addslashes(trim($_POST['bestime']));
//$address = addslashes(trim($_POST['address']));
$origin = addslashes(trim($_POST['origin']));
$destination = addslashes(trim($_POST['destination']));
$msg = addslashes(trim($_POST['msg']));
$brochure = addslashes(trim($_POST['brochure']));




//preparing mail

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\n";
$headers .= "From: $email\n";

$content = 'Name: '.$nameis.'<br>'.
'E-mail: '.$email.'<br>'.
'Phone: '.$phone.'<br>'.
'Message: '.$msg.'<br>'.
'Best Time to Call: '.$bestime.'<br>'.
'Origin: '.$origin.'<br>'.
'Destination: '.$destination.'<br>'.
'Requested Brochure: '.$brochure.'<br>'.
'Time: '.$timestamp.'<br>'.
'IP: '.$host.'<br>'.
'User agent: '.$user_agent;


//sending mail

mail("service@medtransportcenter.com","Los Altos, CA Landing Page Contact", $content, $headers);


?>
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: @Fred It could be worse.

Comment: Just do that `if(isset($_POST['brochure']){` and below that add `$brochure_checked = $_POST['brochure'];} else {$brochure_not_checked = $_POST['brochure'];}`. Something to that affect.

Comment: What syntax error it is displaying?

Comment: This is the syntax error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF, expecting '{'

Comment: I added the above from Fred as a function in the PHP document and called it in the form

Comment: function checkBox()
if(isset($_POST['brochure']){
$brochure_checked = $_POST['brochure'];} 
else {
$brochure_not_checked = $_POST['brochure'];
}

Comment: '<div class="btn-box"><input class="button1" type="submit" onsubmit="return checkBox()" value="Send" tabindex="10" /></div>'

Comment: @MTC: See my answer below.

Comment: I guess I'm too dumb, it's not working, still getting that syntax error

Comment: @MTC Why are you setting it as a **function**?

Comment: @MTC The suggestion I gave you should've gone under your `<?php` and not above `<form id="proForm" action="send-form.php" method="post" >`. Where did you put it? Update your question with the full code, and I'll have a closer look at it.

Comment: @MTC `onsubmit="return checkBox()"` is **"Javascript"**. My suggestion is **PHP** and doesn't belong in `JS`.

Comment: @MTC I made a `Pastebin` file, because I didn't want to post it as an "answer" yet, and want you to try it out first. Visit the following URL and let me know if it works for you. There's something in there though that I'm not 100% sure and I've made a comment in the script about it. Visit this link http://pastebin.com/YqDfHkw6

Comment: Checking it now thanks.

Comment: It still doesn't display as checked in the email : (

Comment: @MTC STOP, made an error on the file. Working on it now.

Comment: @MTC New Pastebin file and I deleted the `[]` in your form for the checkbox. It's not perfect but it works and I have to go. Will come back tomorrow see if I can make it better. Here is the link http://pastebin.com/ENKCgqVR

Comment: WOOHOO!!! Thank you Fred, now displays "Yes" in the email when checked. Thank you very much.

Comment: It doesn't display "No" when not checked, but regardless, thank you sir.

Comment: @MTC Yes I know, I need to work on it. I had to leave, something urgent came up. I'll be back tomorrow, and see if you still need it. Will be a pleasure to fix it up better. And you're welcome. If you want me to post it as an **answer** now, let me know. But I will make it better, regardless.

Comment: Thanks for all the help and that's up to you. Would appreciate it but it's not necessary. Let me know when you post the answer and I will accept it for the question. Thanks again.

Comment: @MTC You're quite welcome. I posted my answer below, cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Well here it is my friend, the final and working version.**

**Tested and working**, complete with a:

Requested Brochure: **YES**
or
Requested Brochure: **NO**  message in your E-mail,
plus I also added an echo'ed "Thank you, your message has been sent..." option at the end.

**The form to use:**

```
<div class="form-box">
<!-- Form -->

<form id="proForm" action="send-form.php" method="post" >

<h2 style="text-align:center;">REQUEST INFO</h2>
        <h3 style="text-align:center;">FREE EXPERT ADVICE</h3>
<div class="form-content">
<!-- Form -->

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">

<!--tr>
<td class="field-full" colspan="2">
    <div class="label"><label for="www"><b>Your website URL</b></label></div>
    <input id="www" class="required defaultInvalidUrl url" maxlength="40" name="www" type="text" tabindex="2" value="http://" />
</td>
</tr-->
<tr>
<th class="label" align="right"><label for="nameis">Your name</label></td>:<td class="field">
  <input id="nameis" class="required defaultInvalidEmail nameis" maxlength="40" name="nameis" type="text" tabindex="2" value="Required" 
        onfocus="if (this.value == 'Required') {this.value = '';}"
        onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Required';}" size="40" />
</td>
</tr>                                   
<tr>
<th class="label" align="right"><label for="email">E-mail</label></td>:<td class="field">
  <input id="email" class="required defaultInvalidEmail email" maxlength="40" name="email" type="text" tabindex="3" value="Required" 
        onfocus="if (this.value == 'Required') {this.value = '';}"
        onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Required';}" size="40" />
</td>
</tr>   

<tr>
<th class="label" align="right"><label for="phone">Best Phone:</label></td>
<td class="field">
  <input id="phone" class="required defaultInvalidEmail phone" maxlength="40" name="phone" type="text" tabindex="4" value="Required" size="30" 
        onfocus="if (this.value == 'Required') {this.value = '';}"
        onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Required';}" size="40" />
</td>
</tr>   

<tr>
<th class="label" align="right"><label for="bestime">
Best time to reach you:</label></td>
<td class="field">
  <input maxlength="40" size="30" name="bestime" type="text" tabindex="5" value="" />
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th class="label" align="right"><label for="phone">
Origin:</label></td>
<td class="field">
  <input maxlength="40" size="30" name="origin" type="text" tabindex="5" value="" />
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th class="label" align="right"><label for="phone">
Destination:</label></td>
<td class="field">
  <input maxlength="40" size="30" name="destination" type="text" tabindex="5" value="" />
</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<th class="label" align="right"><label for="msg">
Message:</label></td>
<td class="field">
  <textarea rows="3" cols="31" name="msg" tabindex="6"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th class="label"><label for="brochure">Request Brochures</label></td>
<td class="field">
  <input type="checkbox" name="brochure"/>
</td>
</tr>       

<!--tr>
<td class="field-full" colspan="2">
    <div class="label"><label for="msg"><b>Other</b></label></div>
  <textarea rows="3" cols="30" name="msg" tabindex="9"></textarea>
</td>
</tr-->

</table>

<div class="terms">By clicking 'Send',<br/> you accept our <a onclick="showTerms()">Privacy Policy</a>. <br /><span style="font-size:14px;">Phone: 800-282-6878.</span></div>

<div class="btn-box"><input class="button1" type="submit" value="Send" tabindex="10" /></div>


<!-- END Form -->
</form> 
</div>
```

**The PHP to use:**

```
<?php

//$www = '';    
$email = '';
$nameis = '';
$phone = '';
$bestime = '';
//$address = '';
$origin = '';
$destination = '';
$msg = '';
$brochure = '';

function getIp()
{
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){
    $ip_address=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
}

if (!isset($ip_address)){
        if (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) 
        $ip_address=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
return $ip_address;
}

if(isset($_POST['brochure'])){
$brochure = "YES";
} 
else {
$brochure = "NO";
}


//taking info about date, IP and user agent

$timestamp = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$ip   = getIp();
$host = gethostbyaddr($ip); 
$user_agent = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];


//taking the data from form 

//$www = addslashes(trim($_POST['www']));   
$email = addslashes(trim($_POST['email']));
$nameis = addslashes(trim($_POST['nameis']));
$phone = addslashes(trim($_POST['phone']));
$bestime = addslashes(trim($_POST['bestime']));
//$address = addslashes(trim($_POST['address']));
$origin = addslashes(trim($_POST['origin']));
$destination = addslashes(trim($_POST['destination']));
$msg = addslashes(trim($_POST['msg']));


//preparing mail

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\n";
$headers .= "From: $email\n";

$content = 'Name: '.$nameis.'<br>'.
'E-mail: '.$email.'<br>'.
'Phone: '.$phone.'<br>'.
'Message: '.$msg.'<br>'.
'Best Time to Call: '.$bestime.'<br>'.
'Origin: '.$origin.'<br>'.
'Destination: '.$destination.'<br>'.
'Requested Brochure: '.$brochure.'<br>'.
'Time: '.$timestamp.'<br>'.
'IP: '.$host.'<br>'.
'User agent: '.$user_agent;


//sending mail

mail("your_email@example.com","Los Altos, CA Landing Page Contact", $content, $headers);

echo "Thank you, your message has been sent. We will contact you as soon as possible.";

?>
```

The way I set it up is I used `isset` from the `POSTed` value, assigned `$brochure` as a variable that, if it is set, the variable equals "YES", and if it is not set, then the same variable equals "NO".

(The code below was added to the PHP, while some other code was removed)

```
if(isset($_POST['brochure'])){
$brochure = "YES";
} 
else {
$brochure = "NO";
}
```

The syntax errors that were happening earlier, is that you used `addslashes` and `trim` for the **checkbox** value, which **caused havoc**.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your script:

- The form does not have a submit button. It's required to send the form inputs to the server.
- You're not validating the form anywhere in your script. That's the reason why it's generating unnecessary errors.
- In your code, you have many of these - `$email = addslashes(trim($_POST['email']));` but you're not accepting the inputs anywhere. Since the input fields doesn't exist, PHP will throw  `Undefined index` errors if you try to echo them.

**HTML:**

```
<form id="proForm" action="send-form.php" method="post" >
<tr>
<th class="label"><label for="brochure">Request Brochures</label></td>
<td class="field">
Email: <input type="text" name="email">
Phone: <input type="text" name="phone">
Bestime: <input type="text" name="bestime">
Origin: <input type="text" name="origin">
Destination: <input type="text" name="destination">
Message: <textarea name="msg">Input message</textarea>
<input type="checkbox" name="brochure" value="Yes" />
<input type="submit" name="submitButton"/>
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
if(isset($_POST['submitButton'])){

//the form was submited, process the inputs below!

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm confused. The form does have a submit button. When I remove that code I just entered and put input into the fields and click submit, I do receive the email with the information that was included.

Comment: @MTC: I don't see it in your question? Have you tried this soltution? Did it work? If not, what's the error?

Comment: Here it is:`<div class="btn-box"><input class="button1" type="submit" onsubmit="return checkBox()" value="Send" tabindex="10" /></div>`

Comment: This is what generates the error: `function checkBox()
if(isset($_POST['brochure']){
$brochure_checked = $_POST['brochure'];} 
else {
$brochure_not_checked = $_POST['brochure'];
}`

Comment: @MTC `onsubmit="return checkBox()"` is Javascript. My suggestion is **PHP**, and doesn't belong inside a Javascript-based function. Re-read my comments in your original question, and post your **FULL CODE** including your **FORM**. You're making me look like a fool.

Comment: You're trying to execute a PHP function with onclick. That would **never** work, in *this* case. Please use the suggested solution. There's no need to define functions here :)

Comment: @AmalMurali You're partially right. It would work, had he been using **Ajax.**

Comment: @Fred: which is why I italicized 'this' in my previous comment.

Comment: @AmalMurali Aahhhh yes, sorry I didn't see that. ;-) well said :)

Answer (score 0):

Your are missing a closing bracket in the first line of your code:

Your Code:

```
if(isset($_POST['brochure']){
// Requested Brochures
}
```

Should be:

```
if(isset($_POST['brochure'])){ //Closing bracket for if added
// Requested Brochures
}
```

Cheers!

[EDIT]
Your Form

```
<div class="form-box">
    <!-- Form -->

    <form id="proForm" action="send-form.php" method="post" >

        <h2 style="text-align:center;">REQUEST INFO</h2>
        <h3 style="text-align:center;">FREE EXPERT ADVICE</h3>
        <div class="form-content">
            <!-- Form -->

            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">

                <!--tr>
                <td class="field-full" colspan="2">
                <div class="label"><label for="www"><b>Your website URL</b></label></div>
                <input id="www" class="required defaultInvalidUrl url" maxlength="40" name="www" type="text" tabindex="2" value="http://" />
                </td>
                </tr-->
                <tr>
                    <th class="label" align="right"><label for="nameis">Your name</label></td>:<td class="field">
                    <input id="nameis" class="required defaultInvalidEmail nameis" maxlength="40" name="nameis" type="text" tabindex="2" value="Required"
                    onfocus="if (this.value == 'Required') {this.value = '';}"
                    onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Required';}" size="40" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="label" align="right"><label for="email">E-mail</label></td>:<td class="field">
                    <input id="email" class="required defaultInvalidEmail email" maxlength="40" name="email" type="text" tabindex="3" value="Required"
                    onfocus="if (this.value == 'Required') {this.value = '';}"
                    onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Required';}" size="40" />
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th class="label" align="right"><label for="phone">Best Phone:</label></td><td class="field">
                    <input id="phone" class="required defaultInvalidEmail phone" maxlength="40" name="phone" type="text" tabindex="4" value="Required" size="30"
                    onfocus="if (this.value == 'Required') {this.value = '';}"
                    onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Required';}" size="40" />
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th class="label" align="right"><label for="bestime"> Best time to reach you:</label></td><td class="field">
                    <input maxlength="40" size="30" name="bestime" type="text" tabindex="5" value="" />
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th class="label" align="right"><label for="phone"> Origin:</label></td><td class="field">
                    <input maxlength="40" size="30" name="origin" type="text" tabindex="5" value="" />
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th class="label" align="right"><label for="phone"> Destination:</label></td><td class="field">
                    <input maxlength="40" size="30" name="destination" type="text" tabindex="5" value="" />
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th class="label" align="right"><label for="msg"> Message:</label></td><td class="field">                   <textarea rows="3" cols="31" name="msg" tabindex="6"></textarea></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th class="label"><label for="brochure">Request Brochures</label></td><td class="field">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="brochure[]" value="Yes" />
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <!--tr>
                <td class="field-full" colspan="2">
                <div class="label"><label for="msg"><b>Other</b></label></div>
                <textarea rows="3" cols="30" name="msg" tabindex="9"></textarea>
                </td>
                </tr-->

            </table>

            <div class="terms">
                By clicking 'Send',
                <br/>
                you accept our <a onclick="showTerms()">Privacy Policy</a>.
                <br />
                <span style="font-size:14px;">Phone: 800-282-6878.</span>
            </div>

            <div class="btn-box">
                <input class="button1" type="submit" value="Send" tabindex="10" />
            </div>

            <!-- END Form -->
    </form>
</div>
```

send-form.php

```
<?php

//$www = '';
$email = '';
$nameis = '';
$phone = '';
$bestime = '';
//$address = '';
$origin = '';
$destination = '';
$msg = '';
$brochure = '';
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";

function getIp() {
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        $ip_address = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }

    if (!isset($ip_address)) {
        if (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))
            $ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip_address;
}

if (isset($_POST['brochure'])) {
    $brochure_checked = $_POST['brochure'];
} else {
    //$brochure_checked = "no"; //no could be any value you want because the check box is not checked
    // or 
    //if you want to use it in post super global you can set it as  
    $_POST['brochure'] = array('no'); // the value is returned in array if the brochure is set so i am using array here
}

//taking info about date, IP and user agent

$timestamp = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$ip = getIp();
$host = gethostbyaddr($ip);
$user_agent = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];

//taking the data from form

//$www = addslashes(trim($_POST['www']));
$email = addslashes(trim($_POST['email']));
$nameis = addslashes(trim($_POST['nameis']));
$phone = addslashes(trim($_POST['phone']));
$bestime = addslashes(trim($_POST['bestime']));
//$address = addslashes(trim($_POST['address']));
$origin = addslashes(trim($_POST['origin']));
$destination = addslashes(trim($_POST['destination']));
$msg = addslashes(trim($_POST['msg']));
$brochure = addslashes(trim($_POST['brochure'][0])); //now you can use this value here
var_dump($brochure);

//preparing mail

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\n";
$headers .= "From: $email\n";

$content = 'Name: ' . $nameis . '<br>' . 'E-mail: ' . $email . '<br>' . 'Phone: ' . $phone . '<br>' . 'Message: ' . $msg . '<br>' . 'Best Time to Call: ' . $bestime . '<br>' . 'Origin: ' . $origin . '<br>' . 'Destination: ' . $destination . '<br>' . 'Requested Brochure: ' . $brochure . '<br>' . 'Time: ' . $timestamp . '<br>' . 'IP: ' . $host . '<br>' . 'User agent: ' . $user_agent;

//sending mail

mail("abc@medtransportcenter.com", "Los Altos, CA Landing Page Contact", $content, $headers);
?>
```

**Explanation:**

What happen is the `$_POST['brochure']` is set only when the checkbox is checked. In your code you are using it as:

```
if(isset($_POST['brochure'])){
 $brochure_checked = $_POST['brochure'];} 
else {
 $brochure_not_checked = $_POST['brochure'];
}
```

If the brochure field is set then you will get the value. But look at your else condition, you are assigning the value that doesn't exists. And this statement `$brochure = addslashes(trim($_POST['brochure']));` is now trying to trim the value that doesn't exists. Check the edited code. Hope it works! I have used comments in the edited part.

Comment: Why -1? It answers the question about the syntax error he has mentioned.

Comment: Thank you. This does solve the syntax error, I'm dumb don't know how I missed that.

Comment: But It still doesn't show the input when form is submitted that the checkbox was checked